# Migrating a HTML / CSS designed website template to google web toolkit?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm working on a website, for which an existing web template is being used. All the screens / forms of the website, have already been designed into HTML / CSS. Specifically the template is based on bootstrap.

From what I remember of GWT when I last looked into it, you had to design the UI from within a java class. You were able to change the css code / classes, but you couldn't modify the html code which was generated.

That's a problem for me, as I'm looking for a way to be able to re-use the html and css code which I already have. What's the best way to do that with GWT? Essentially, I want my GWT site to look exactly the same as it does now with pure html / css.

Comment: You could have a look at Errai (http://erraiframework.org/). It supports the usage of html based templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats pretty simple. You can keep your page exactly how it is.
Theres no need to change your HTML or CSS at all.

All you need to do is add a little bit to the HTML to load the GWT (which is invisible and wont effect anything else). 
Then you need to do is give ID's to any element you want GWT to be able to interact with.
Then, within the Java code, you can either replace these elements or change them as you wish.

For example;

```
Element MyDiv = DOM.getElementById("left-content")
```

Would get this Div in your html;

```
<Div ID="left-content">Content!</div>
```

You could then edit that content, apply or remove styles etc.

You can also use the RootPanel,
If you want to add something new into the Div;

```
Label testlabel = new Label("Test....");
RootPanel.get("left-content").add(testlabel);
```

Or just add something to the page at a certain position (floating)

```
Image testimage= new Image ("testimage.png");
RootPanel.get().add(testimage);
```

None of these would effect whats on the page already if you dont want them too.
Likewise, you can add and remove existing styles controlled from your existing css.

In other words; You *can* let GWT generate HTML and Styles, but you certainly dont have too.

Comment: Thanks. One question. If I do the server-side with GWT as well, is it possible to make a .war file out of it? Alternatively, if I did the server-side with a framework like Struts2, can that integrate with gwt on the client side easily?

Comment: Also.. if my existing html already contains form elements (textboxes, etc), is it possible to get the existing textboxes etc too using their id?

Comment: I confess I am not sure.
I think so. You can with images at least, I believe its called "wrap Element"

Answer (score 1):

**I THINK** the solution of @darkflame is applicable if you have only  One html page in the whole website, so the problem is how to manage & navigate between all pages ?

**MY HUMBLE SUGGESTIONS :**
-first solution (very bad one) consists of copying all your html pages inside GWT main html page, then use a lot of setVisible(true/false) to simulate navigation between pages then use the solution above..

-second solution is create your website from "scratch" using GWT best practice [GWT MVP](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html)

you can use Twitter-Bootstrap, take a look here  [Bootstrap for Gwt](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap)

Comment: The first solution you mention could also be done with hiding/showing Frame objects (effectively iFrames), that way the original pages could be used without copying it all into one host page.
You could also use the "HTMLPanel" object to load html in from a file and put it in a div. That might be better as you can reference elements with IDs still. 
http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~HTMLPanel
You would have to get the HTML from the server using a request call, however.

Comment: @darkflame That example you showed, has the html hardcoded into a string. How would I fetch the html from the server?

Comment: You need to use a Request:

  RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,"url/here.html");

Then use;
"requestBuilder.sendRequest(..." to send the request, but you need to provide a callback as to what to do when it gets the information.

Comment: as you can see, your code will groth quickly and you need a way to organize it, and it is not an easy task, MVP is an option..

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your HTML and CSS code as is and use GwtQuery (the native version of jQuery for GWT) to interact with your HTML and insert your GWT code.